# Is a DbContext per thread in Parallel.ForEach safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, parallel-processing, entity-framework-6

I am working a contract right now to increase the performance of a back end services for a modern SaaS SPA web app that is using EF 6 as their ORM. The first thing I proposed was to introduce some multi-threading to their  back end service which is currently running single threaded. The lead software engineer has indicated we cannot do that because EF 6 is not thread-safe.

I am no expert on Entity Framework. My ORM of choice is XPO by DevExpress and I have done something similar to what is proposed below without issue using that ORM. Is this pattern inherently not safe using EF 6?

```
int[] ids;
using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
{
    // query to surface id's of records representing work to be done
    ids = GetIdsOfRecordsRepresentingSomeTask(db);
}

Parallel.ForEach(ids, id => { 
    using(var db = new ApplicationDbContext())
    {
        var processor = new SomeTaskProcessor(db, id);
        processor.ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords();
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
});
```

I have researched this, and I agree that DbContext is not thread-safe. The pattern I propose does use multiple threads, but a single DbContext is only every accessed by a single thread in a single-threaded fashion. The lead is telling me that DbContext is essentially a singleton under the covers and this code would ultimately mess up the database. I can't find anything to support this claim. Is the lead right on this?

Thanks

Comment: LGTM. The main reason we shouldn't use multiple threads with a `DbContext` is because ADO.NET does not allow concurrent active `DbCommand` execution (even in a single-threaded environment using `async`/`await`). That said, make sure you don't run too many threads beause the bottleneck here will be the database server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pattern is thread-safe. However, at least for SQL Server, if your concurrency is too high, you'll find that your total throughput drops off as contention for database resources increases.

In theory, Parallel.ForEach optimizes the number of threads, but in practice, I have found it allows too much concurrency in my applications.

You can control concurrency with the [ParallelOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions?view=netframework-4.8) optional parameter. Test your use case and see if the default concurrency works well for you.

Your comment: *Keeping in mind that, right now anyway, that we are talking about 100's of ids in that code above where most id's represent work that does not end up in any changes to the database and are short lived while a hand full can take minutes to complete and ultimately add 10's of new records to the DB. What MaxDegreesOfParallelism value would you recommend off the top of your head?*

Probably 2-3 based on your general description, but it depends on how database intensive `ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords` is (vs. performing CPU-bound activities or waiting for IO from files, web service calls, etc). With more than that, if that method is mostly performing DB tasks, you're likely to get locking contention or overwhelm your IO subsystem (disks). Test in your environment to be sure.

It may be worth exploring why `ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords` is taking so long to complete for a given Id.

**UPDATE**

Here's some test code to demonstrate that the threads do not block each other and indeed run concurrently. I removed the DbContext portion for simplicity and since it doesn't affect the threading issue.

```
class SomeTaskProcessor
{
    static Random rng = new Random();
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public SomeTaskProcessor(int id) { Id = id; }
    public void ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting ID {Id}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(1000));
        Console.WriteLine($"Completing ID {Id}");
    }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();

        Parallel.ForEach(ids, id => {
                var processor = new SomeTaskProcessor(id);
                processor.ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Eric. Keeping in mind that, right now anyway, that we are talking about 100's of ids in that code above where most id's represent work that does not end up in any changes to the database and are short lived while a hand full can take minutes to complete and ultimately add 10's of new records to the DB. What MaxDegreesOfParallelism value would you recommend off the top of your head?

Comment: My answer was a little long for a comment so updated above.

Comment: Ahh - yes I should have included that detail. In this instance the task being performed is very much IO bound calling out to third party web API to collect required information for processing. Once all the data is collected, it is processed and may result in some new records needing to be added to the database. There are a few queries to collect some additional information during the processing phase, but all those are performing fine.

Comment: In that case, you can likely get away with rather high concurrency. Start without specifying any concurrency limit in Parallel.ForEach and see how it performs.

Comment: I am afraid in this case parallelism is not going to help.

Comment: @dropoutcoder Yes, it will. The parallelism allows multiple external web API calls to be made concurrently. Those are likely to be a huge component of overall performance.

Comment: @EricJ.: Those calls are synchronous. They are blocking threads that you cannot use for parallelism. Minimum gain there. (if I am not extremely wrong)

Comment: @EricJ.: Another problem is that parallel execution is not guaranteed.

Comment: @dropoutcoder: Parallel runs the code specified by the lambda expression on one or more threads. You may be confusing asynchronous programming with multithreading. This isn't an async/await scenario. Yes, parallel execution is not guaranteed. Yes, the runtime may decide to execute on a single thread. In practice, it will do so when the current CPU load is fairly high AND the code it's executing is fairly CPU bound. Since the OP states the core method is heavy on internet IO, it should run a number of threads.

Comment: @EricJ.: I never said threads are blocking each other or waiting for each other. I am still saying thread is blocked.  by sync call to 3rd party API and/or database calls(`SaveChanges()`). I am not confusing async programming with multithreading. Also I think it is async/await scenario with heavy internet IO. It just needs to be done the right way.

Comment: As far as the scenario is presented, it doesn't matter that the thread is blocked because you'll use a small number of threads compared to system capacity. If it turns out that a particular scenario does spawn a great number of threads, you can use async/await inside of the long-running process to interact with the various web APIs, and you can use SaveChangesAsync() in this code.

Answer (score 0):

**Issue #1 - Memory Allocation**

Every single iteration will create instance of `DbContext` which will lead to memory allocations. Garbage collector will need to deal with those allocations. If there will be constant memory pressure it will end up in performance degradation on application level.

**Issue #2 - SQL overload**

Based on written above during every single iteration you'll call `SaveChanges()` that will probably make a call to database. In case call to the database is/will be resource intensive you may end up with poorly performing database.

**Issue #3 - Thread blocking**

`SaveChanges()` is synchronous and will block the thread. In situation call to database takes significant amount of time, thread will just sit and wait. Same for 3rd party API calls. There will be no or small performance gain.

**Issue #4 - Parallel.For* methods are not guaranteed to run in parallel**

> It is important to keep in mind that individual iterations in a Parallel.For, Parallel.ForEach or ForAll loop may but do not have to execute in parallel.

I think this is self explanatory.

[Potential Pitfalls with PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/potential-pitfalls-with-plinq)

[Understanding Speedup in PLINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/understanding-speedup-in-plinq)

---

I am reading comments under the question and Eric J. answer I am afraid there is problem with approach to the problem and parallelism is not going to help.

> Thanks for the answer Eric. Keeping in mind that, right now anyway, that we are talking about 100's of ids in that code above where most id's represent work that does not end up in any changes to the database and are short lived while a hand full can take minutes to complete and ultimately add 10's of new records to the DB. What MaxDegreesOfParallelism value would you recommend off the top of your head?
>
> Ahh - yes I should have included that detail. In this instance the task being performed is very much IO bound calling out to third party web API to collect required information for processing. Once all the data is collected, it is processed and may result in some new records needing to be added to the database. There are a few queries to collect some additional information during the processing phase, but all those are performing fine.

If I am not completely wrong the problem are calls to 3rd party API synchronously, which blocks the thread.

I think async approach might help here to gather data from 3rd party API.

Also would help not allocating heap memory if not necessary. You can save changes at the end of execution with just one `DbContext` instance and just one database call.

---

**UPDATE**

Eric J. added test to test threads are not blocking each other(which they don't) and to test concurrent execution. Code below is his original code provided in his answer.

```
class SomeTaskProcessor
{
    static Random rng = new Random();
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public SomeTaskProcessor(int id) { Id = id; }
    public void ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting ID {Id}");
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(rng.Next(1000));
        Console.WriteLine($"Completing ID {Id}");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int[] ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();

        Parallel.ForEach(ids, id => {
                var processor = new SomeTaskProcessor(id);
                processor.ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords();
        });
    }
}
```

I made similar test. I created server to simulate internet IO with delayed response of 1 second. Before each test run API server was started and first request made. Test were run in Release config.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ValuesController : ControllerBase {
    // GET api/values
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<string>>> Get() {
        await Task.Delay(1000);

        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }
}
```

I have updated his code to call API endpoint. On my virtual machine it spun 5 thread and was executing on average 23 seconds.

```
class SomeTaskProcessor {
    private HttpClient http = new HttpClient() {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49890/api/values")
    };

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public SomeTaskProcessor(int id) { Id = id; }
    public void ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords() {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting ID {Id}. Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
        var response = http.GetAsync(String.Empty).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        Console.WriteLine($"Completing ID {Id}. Response status code is {response.StatusCode}. Thread Id: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
    }
}

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        int[] ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();;

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        Parallel.ForEach(ids, id => {
            var processor = new SomeTaskProcessor(id);
            processor.ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords();
        });

        // ~23 seconds

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Starting ID 51. Thread Id: 4
Starting ID 1. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 2. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 52. Thread Id: 9
Starting ID 3. Thread Id: 12
Completing ID 51. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 4
Starting ID 53. Thread Id: 4
Completing ID 2. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 4. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 55. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 6. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 52. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Starting ID 56. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 1. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 7. Thread Id: 1
Completing ID 3. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 12
Starting ID 9. Thread Id: 12
Starting ID 58. Thread Id: 16
Completing ID 53. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 4
Starting ID 54. Thread Id: 4
Completing ID 4. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 5. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 11. Thread Id: 18
Completing ID 55. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 59. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 61. Thread Id: 20
Completing ID 56. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Starting ID 57. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 7. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 8. Thread Id: 1
Completing ID 9. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 12
Starting ID 10. Thread Id: 12
Completing ID 6. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Starting ID 12. Thread Id: 15
Starting ID 14. Thread Id: 22
Completing ID 5. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 15. Thread Id: 5
Completing ID 54. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 4
Starting ID 62. Thread Id: 4
Completing ID 58. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 16
Starting ID 66. Thread Id: 16
Starting ID 68. Thread Id: 23
Completing ID 11. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 18
Starting ID 19. Thread Id: 18
Completing ID 59. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 60. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 21. Thread Id: 24
Completing ID 57. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Starting ID 69. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 12. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Starting ID 13. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 61. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 20
Starting ID 73. Thread Id: 20
Completing ID 10. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 12
Completing ID 8. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 22. Thread Id: 12
Starting ID 26. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 75. Thread Id: 25
Completing ID 15. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 16. Thread Id: 5
Completing ID 62. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 4
Starting ID 63. Thread Id: 4
Completing ID 66. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 16
Starting ID 67. Thread Id: 16
Completing ID 14. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 22
Starting ID 30. Thread Id: 22
Starting ID 32. Thread Id: 26
Starting ID 76. Thread Id: 27
Completing ID 60. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 77. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 19. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 18
Starting ID 20. Thread Id: 18
Completing ID 69. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Starting ID 70. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 21. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 24
Starting ID 33. Thread Id: 24
Completing ID 13. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Starting ID 35. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 73. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 20
Starting ID 74. Thread Id: 20
Completing ID 22. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 12
Starting ID 23. Thread Id: 12
Completing ID 26. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 27. Thread Id: 1
Completing ID 68. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 23
Starting ID 81. Thread Id: 23
Starting ID 39. Thread Id: 29
Completing ID 67. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 16
Starting ID 83. Thread Id: 16
Completing ID 75. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 25
Completing ID 30. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 22
Starting ID 31. Thread Id: 22
Completing ID 16. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 87. Thread Id: 25
Starting ID 17. Thread Id: 5
Completing ID 63. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 4
Starting ID 64. Thread Id: 4
Starting ID 89. Thread Id: 30
Completing ID 76. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 27
Starting ID 90. Thread Id: 27
Completing ID 32. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 26
Starting ID 40. Thread Id: 26
Completing ID 77. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 78. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 42. Thread Id: 31
Completing ID 70. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Starting ID 71. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 27. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 28. Thread Id: 1
Completing ID 74. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 20
Starting ID 92. Thread Id: 20
Completing ID 35. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Starting ID 36. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 81. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 23
Starting ID 82. Thread Id: 23
Completing ID 33. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 24
Starting ID 34. Thread Id: 24
Completing ID 20. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 18
Starting ID 43. Thread Id: 18
Completing ID 23. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 12
Starting ID 24. Thread Id: 12
Starting ID 96. Thread Id: 32
Completing ID 39. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 29
Completing ID 17. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 18. Thread Id: 5
Starting ID 47. Thread Id: 29
Completing ID 64. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 4
Starting ID 65. Thread Id: 4
Completing ID 87. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 25
Starting ID 88. Thread Id: 25
Completing ID 31. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 22
Completing ID 83. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 16
Starting ID 84. Thread Id: 16
Starting ID 49. Thread Id: 22
Starting ID 97. Thread Id: 33
Completing ID 90. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 27
Starting ID 91. Thread Id: 27
Completing ID 40. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 26
Starting ID 41. Thread Id: 26
Completing ID 89. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 30
Starting ID 98. Thread Id: 30
Completing ID 78. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 79. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 100. Thread Id: 34
Completing ID 36. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Starting ID 37. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 92. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 20
Starting ID 93. Thread Id: 20
Completing ID 42. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 31
Completing ID 28. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 29. Thread Id: 1
Completing ID 24. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 12
Starting ID 25. Thread Id: 12
Completing ID 82. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 23
Completing ID 71. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Starting ID 72. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 43. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 18
Starting ID 44. Thread Id: 18
Completing ID 96. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 32
Completing ID 65. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 4
Completing ID 88. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 25
Completing ID 49. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 22
Starting ID 50. Thread Id: 22
Completing ID 47. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 29
Starting ID 48. Thread Id: 29
Completing ID 18. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 5
Completing ID 34. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 24
Completing ID 84. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 16
Starting ID 85. Thread Id: 16
Completing ID 97. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 33
Completing ID 41. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 26
Completing ID 79. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Starting ID 80. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 100. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 34
Completing ID 93. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 20
Starting ID 94. Thread Id: 20
Completing ID 29. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 1
Completing ID 98. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 30
Starting ID 99. Thread Id: 30
Completing ID 44. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 18
Starting ID 45. Thread Id: 18
Completing ID 25. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 12
Completing ID 37. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Starting ID 38. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 72. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 91. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 27
Completing ID 50. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 22
Completing ID 48. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 29
Completing ID 85. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 16
Starting ID 86. Thread Id: 16
Completing ID 80. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 94. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 20
Starting ID 95. Thread Id: 20
Completing ID 99. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 30
Completing ID 45. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 18
Starting ID 46. Thread Id: 18
Completing ID 38. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 86. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 16
Completing ID 95. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 20
Completing ID 46. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 18
00:00:23.6046580

C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 7208) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

Then I created async version of the same code. Execition took on average 7 seconds.

```
class SomeTaskProcessor {
    private HttpClient http = new HttpClient() {
        BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:49890/api/values")
    };

    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public SomeTaskProcessor(int id) { Id = id; }
    public async Task ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords() {
        Console.WriteLine($"Starting ID {Id}");
        var response = await http.GetAsync(String.Empty);
        Console.WriteLine($"Completing ID {Id}. Response status code is {response.StatusCode}");
    }
}

class Program {
    static async Task Main(string[] args) {
        int[] ids = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();;

        var stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        var tasks = ids.Select(id => {
            var processor = new SomeTaskProcessor(id);
            return processor.ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords();
        }).ToArray();

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        // ~8 seconds

        stopwatch.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString());
    }
}
```

Console output:

```
Starting ID 1. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 2. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 3. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 4. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 5. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 6. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 7. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 8. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 9. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 10. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 11. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 12. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 13. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 14. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 15. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 16. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 17. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 18. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 19. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 20. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 21. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 22. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 23. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 24. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 25. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 26. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 27. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 28. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 29. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 30. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 31. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 32. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 33. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 34. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 35. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 36. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 37. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 38. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 39. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 40. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 41. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 42. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 43. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 44. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 45. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 46. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 47. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 48. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 49. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 50. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 51. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 52. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 53. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 54. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 55. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 56. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 57. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 58. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 59. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 60. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 61. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 62. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 63. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 64. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 65. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 66. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 67. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 68. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 69. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 70. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 71. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 72. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 73. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 74. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 75. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 76. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 77. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 78. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 79. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 80. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 81. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 82. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 83. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 84. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 85. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 86. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 87. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 88. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 89. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 90. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 91. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 92. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 93. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 94. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 95. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 96. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 97. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 98. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 99. Thread Id: 1
Starting ID 100. Thread Id: 1
Completing ID 3. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 10. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 8. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 7. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 11. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 4. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 9. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 12. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 13. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 6. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 17. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 18. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 21. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 24. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 20. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 30. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 22. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 34. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 32. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 33. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 39. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 35. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 2. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 44. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 23. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 31. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 38. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 43. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 50. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 1. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 48. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 27. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 49. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 28. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 14. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 29. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 26. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 15. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 19. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 25. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 5. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 40. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 60. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 37. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 41. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 16. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 63. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 36. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 42. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 45. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 64. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 53. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 61. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 52. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 67. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 74. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 75. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 62. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 78. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 66. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 55. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 83. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 59. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 68. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 85. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 47. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 72. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 65. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 84. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 70. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 87. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 56. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 90. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 76. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 73. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 69. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 86. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 81. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 91. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 77. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 57. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 98. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 100. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 79. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 58. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 80. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 82. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 89. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 88. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 97. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 51. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 94. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 93. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 71. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 46. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 54. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
Completing ID 95. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 15
Completing ID 92. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 8
Completing ID 99. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 14
Completing ID 96. Response status code is OK. Thread Id: 9
00:00:06.7737961

C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet.exe (process 296) exited with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
Press any key to close this window . . .
```

I believe 23 seconds vs 7 seconds are enough of proof to say it is async/await scenario.

Comment: #1 - DbContext instances are lightweight and backed by a pool of DB connections. No real memory pressure (you'll only have probably one per CPU core alive at any time, and they are fairly cheap to allocate and dispose compared to web IO). #2 - Yes, but the level of concurrency can be limited as indicated in my answer. #3 - There are multiple threads. They don't block each other. You may be confusing this with async/await. #4 - True, but they will. See my comment above.

Comment: Added sample code to my answer to demonstrate that the threads run concurrently.

Comment: @EricJ.: I have added my solution to demonstrate it is async/await scenario and the performance gain is significant.

Comment: As I said, async/await may be entirely appropriate in the long-running method body. The test as you have constructed it causes more concurrent threads to execute than Parallel opts to use. That's why it's faster (but if you connect to something other than localhost, the difference will be smaller). You ask the runtime to start one task per ID. Manually starting tasks may or may not be better than Parallel in the OPs actual case.

Comment: @EricJ.: I am answering based on minimum context provided in OP. I only assume `ExecuteLongRunningProcessThatReadsDbAndCreatesSomeNewRecords()` method is really long-running method. In the end it is up to Casey Chester to evaluate our answers and pick the best fit for his scenario. That's all.